# Sage CRM - It is possible to add a Terriroy field to the team entity?

Tags: sage-crm

As the title says, it is possible?

I see that the Company entity has a comp_secterr (Zones) but it not displayed in the Admin > Custimization > Company > Fields. This field is hardcoded in the company entity?

Im guessing that it would be a select field with a predefined search family but i can not find the territory list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that you need to add a select field to the team entity (Channel table). However, you also need to tell the system to treat it as a Territory field, which you can only do directly in the database.

1) Go to Administration > Customisation > Secondary Entities > Team
2) Add a new field:

```
Entry Type: Selection
Column Name: chan_secterr
Caption: Territory
Lookup Type: Create New Lookup
```

3) Run this query in SQL Management Studio:

```
UPDATE custom_Edits SET colp_entrytype = 53 WHERE colp_colname = 'chan_secterr'
```

4) Perform a Metadata Refresh (Administration > System > Metadata > Refresh All)
5) Add the field to a screen and it should show all the Territories.

Six Ticks Support

Comment: Wow Thanks! Thought, this could be a problem in the future? Mostly because if i go the screen of fields of the Team Entity i see that chan_secterr field type is a 53 lol and looking in the DDBB some columns looks wrong when comparing the row to comp_secterr row. For example: ColP_DataType column is NULL in comp_secterr but 4 in chan_secterr ColP_CustomTableDFK column is 5 in comp_secterr  but 23 in chan_secterr and maybe some other minor stuff (i think)

Comment: It should be fine, but you can always update the fields and see what happens, assuming you have a test environment and backups. You might want to change the colp_datatype field, but I doubt you need the colp_customtabledfk setting.